# GLPK: meaning of the "marginal' column in the solution output

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, solver

I'm using [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) to solve an LP.
I use it through its standalone solver, that I call with the `glpsol` command, and I get the solution detail written in a file using the `-o`/`--output` option.

I have no problem parsing the file to recover the actual solution, but I'm wondering what is the meaning of the "marginal" column.
Here is what the output file looks like:

```
Problem:    
Rows:       60
Columns:    9821
Non-zeros:  405355
Status:     OPTIMAL
Objective:  obj = 1.355170551 (MINimum)

   No.   Row name   St   Activity     Lower bound   Upper bound    Marginal
------ ------------ -- ------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
     1 r.9825       B        1.07478             1               
     2 r.17470      NL             1             1                   0.0287012 
     3 r.24250      B        1.23575             1               
     4 r.31488      NL             1             1                       < eps
     5 r.38796      B         1.0038             1               
     6 r.44423      B        1.03857             1               
     7 r.50832      NL             1             1                   0.0109038 
     8 r.57288      NL             1             1                   0.0233011 
// some more rows ......

   No. Column name  St   Activity     Lower bound   Upper bound    Marginal
------ ------------ -- ------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
     1 Z1           NL             0             0                    0.233221 
     2 Z2           NL             0             0                    0.174953 
     3 Z3           NL             0             0                    0.157688 
     4 Z4           NL             0             0                    0.164336 
     5 Z5           NL             0             0                     0.20934 
     6 Z6           NL             0             0                    0.124799 
[ .... ]
   237 Z237         NL             0             0                   0.0686442 
   238 Z238         NL             0             0                    0.159257 
   239 Z239         B      0.0424075             0               
   240 Z240         NL             0             0                   0.0370097 
   241 Z241         NL             0             0                    0.324198 
[ .... ]
```

The actual values I'm looking for are actually referred to as "activity" (my decision variables being the `Zn`).
But what does `marginal` represent? And, while I'm here, why are the solution values called `activity` (there must be a historical/theoretical reason, and I'm interested)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [GLPK Wikibook page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Solution_information), "marginal" shows the *reduced cost* of your variable.

About why the primal values of the variables are called activity, my guess is the following quote from the [reference manual for GLPK](http://most.ccib.rutgers.edu/glpk.pdf) (page 93):

> ... Since the variable being analyzed is non-basic, its activity, which is
>   equal to its active bound, also starts changing...